# Integrate Azure Bot with SPFX Extension

Tags: spfx, chatbot

I want to call my azure bot from sharepoint online site using spfx extension as shown in the example:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-msal-bot

Steps/Procedure I followed:
1). Clone the repository from git
2). gulp commands and creating the package
3). adding to site collection
4). running gulp serve --nobrowser

same steps I followed as per given example but I am not sure my azure is not yet connected with the extension :(. still do i need to do any thing or am I not following properly.

Please can any one assist me properly on this. Thanks in advance.
[image]